# application works fine on simulator but crashes on device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4.1

i develop my application on xcode 4.1 . When i trie it with iphone 4.3 simulator , it work fine. But when i tries it on my iphone 4 , ios 4.3.3 , it crash. How can i find the problem ? 
i use ASIHTTPRequest, it can be the problem ?

this is the crash log if it can help someone put me on the track of the problem

```
Hardware Model:      iPhone3,1
Process:         MyApp [1018]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/9D725E2D-DF8A-4B01-9FB1-F80D71A6CF9E/MyApp.app/MyApp
Identifier:      MyApp
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  crunchd [1]

Date/Time:       2011-12-09 17:42:17.026 +0100
OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.3.3 (8J2)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3558fa1c __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x356663b4 pthread_kill + 52
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3565ebf8 abort + 72
3   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x35628a64 __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler() + 376
4   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3449d06c _objc_terminate + 104
5   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x35626e36 __cxxabiv1::__terminate(void (*)()) + 46
6   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x35626e8a std::terminate() + 10
7   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x35626f5a __cxa_throw + 78
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3449bc84 objc_exception_throw + 64
9   CoreFoundation                  0x309841b8 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 96
10  CoreFoundation                  0x30983642 ___forwarding___ + 502
11  CoreFoundation                  0x308fa178 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 40
12  MyApp                           0x00004cc0 -[FirstViewController showTest] (FirstViewController.m:447)
13  MyApp                           0x0000471c -[FirstViewController request:didLoad:] (FirstViewController.m:384)
14  MyApp                           0x0000cfc8 -[FBRequest handleResponseData:] (FBRequest.m:261)
15  MyApp                           0x0000d5f6 -[FBRequest connectionDidFinishLoading:] (FBRequest.m:346)
16  Foundation                      0x341c52ee -[NSURLConnection(NSURLConnectionReallyInternal) sendDidFinishLoading] + 62
17  Foundation                      0x341c5270 _NSURLConnectionDidFinishLoading + 72
18  CFNetwork                       0x34c3f40a URLConnectionClient::_clientDidFinishLoading(URLConnectionClient::ClientConnectionEventQueue*) + 130
19  CFNetwork                       0x34c33f3e URLConnectionClient::ClientConnectionEventQueue::processAllEventsAndConsumePayload(XConnectionEventInfo<XClientEvent, XClientEventParams>*, long) + 94
20  CFNetwork                       0x34c340c6 URLConnectionClient::ClientConnectionEventQueue::processAllEventsAndConsumePayload(XConnectionEventInfo<XClientEvent, XClientEventParams>*, long) + 486
21  CFNetwork                       0x34c33e30 URLConnectionClient::processEvents() + 64
22  CFNetwork                       0x34c33de2 URLConnection::multiplexerClientPerform(RunLoopMultiplexer*) + 30
23  CFNetwork                       0x34c33d54 MultiplexerSource::perform() + 120
24  CFNetwork                       0x34c33cd2 MultiplexerSource::_perform(void*) + 2
25  CoreFoundation                  0x30957a72 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 6
26  CoreFoundation                  0x30959758 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 376
27  CoreFoundation                  0x3095a4e4 __CFRunLoopRun + 224
28  CoreFoundation                  0x308eaebc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
29  CoreFoundation                  0x308eadc4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
30  GraphicsServices                0x30269418 GSEventRunModal + 108
31  GraphicsServices                0x302694c4 GSEventRun + 56
32  UIKit                           0x30a10d62 -[UIApplication _run] + 398
33  UIKit                           0x30a0e800 UIApplicationMain + 664
34  MyApp                           0x00002b2c main (main.m:14)
35  MyApp                           0x00002ad4 start + 32

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35590fbc kevent + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x35261032 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 706
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3526203a _dispatch_queue_invoke + 86
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x352615ea _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 186
4   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3566758a _pthread_wqthread + 258
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35667bbc start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2 name:  WebThread
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3558dc00 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3558d758 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x309582b8 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 88
3   CoreFoundation                  0x3095a562 __CFRunLoopRun + 350
4   CoreFoundation                  0x308eaebc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
5   CoreFoundation                  0x308eadc4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
6   WebCore                         0x35f5327e _ZL12RunWebThreadPv + 382
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3566630a _pthread_start + 242
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35667bb4 thread_start + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3558dc00 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3558d758 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x309582b8 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 88
3   CoreFoundation                  0x3095a562 __CFRunLoopRun + 350
4   CoreFoundation                  0x308eaebc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
5   CoreFoundation                  0x308eadc4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
6   Foundation                      0x341dd7f6 +[NSURLConnection(NSURLConnectionReallyInternal) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 206
7   Foundation                      0x341d0382 -[NSThread main] + 38
8   Foundation                      0x342425c6 __NSThread__main__ + 966
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3566630a _pthread_start + 242
10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x35667bb4 thread_start + 0

Thread 4 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3558dc2c semaphore_signal_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3558df92 semaphore_signal + 2
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x356645f4 pthread_mutex_unlock + 188
3   CoreFoundation                  0x308fc3f0 CFRunLoopWakeUp + 84
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3095dc0e __CFSocketManager + 1378
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3566630a _pthread_start + 242
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35667bb4 thread_start + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000001      r3: 0x00000000
    r4: 0x3f31548c    r5: 0x00000006      r6: 0x1eda0d5c      r7: 0x2fe253f8
    r8: 0x31307c7a    r9: 0x00000065     r10: 0x3e7d2b98     r11: 0x00000000
    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x2fe253ec      lr: 0x35c4d3bb      pc: 0x35b76a1c
  cpsr: 0x080f0010

Binary Images:
   0x28000 -    0x7dfff +MyApp armv7  <d503e69ae96b38c29f74f9fd27c88b08> /var/mobile/Applications/9D725E2D-DF8A-4B01-9FB1-F80D71A6CF9E/MyApp.app/MyApp
   0xc3000 -    0xc3fff +MobileSubstrate.dylib armv6  <4070bd34b2c273416bcec248fd8b873d> /Library/MobileSubstrate/MobileSubstrate.dylib
   0xf2000 -    0xf3fff +SubstrateLoader.dylib armv6  <ff6a576a67626b81229111c8c4169d09> /Library/Frameworks/CydiaSubstrate.framework/Libraries/SubstrateLoader.dylib
 0x1119000 -  0x113efff +Activator.dylib armv6  <a930347f472e332ba6a2f6809f12e335> /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/Activator.dylib
 0x114f000 -  0x1153fff +IntelliStatusIconsView.dylib armv6  <915699e8cb5c1a129984cec679515c50> /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/IntelliStatusIconsView.dylib
 0x115d000 -  0x115efff +sandcastleclient.dylib armv6  <d138ce2db8b033aba6119acf3d561535> /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/sandcastleclient.dylib
 0x1161000 -  0x1164fff  libsubstrate.dylib armv6  <5f24c4f6863b75d701ee663ed761c423> /usr/lib/libsubstrate.dylib
0x2fe27000 - 0x2fe4cfff  dyld armv7  <bb9bfc7d242331d29a79adf7ef7aaa18> /usr/lib/dyld
0x305ec000 - 0x30615fff  MobileCoreServices armv7  <57fef84bdc17301d8bf53ba0fb967fe6> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x30616000 - 0x3064dfff  Security armv7  <6599f42a910b3b31a0e1d98c883d61cb> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x3064e000 - 0x3064ffff  libsystem_network.dylib armv7  <39bf0f48bd8539169a77f8f61cdcd4c9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x306ac000 - 0x306acfff  Accelerate armv7  <7d5ad465049136afaa1f0d89aac600bc> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x307aa000 - 0x3083ffff  ImageIO armv7  <d520e3241d1130e8ac1375ee0f2c1095> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x3084c000 - 0x30858fff  GraphicsServices armv7  <ff78a9636e933f0dbd222f8d26209788> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x309b7000 - 0x309b9fff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv7  <a2631ac302f4310dae8367939e16b7c2> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x309ba000 - 0x30ad4fff  libicucore.A.dylib armv7  <bada0c2725bb31a483d5adf9aaf1f8df> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x30ad9000 - 0x30aeffff  EAP8021X armv7  <9fefc0ada30435fbb3b51818c74f6cb8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x30c91000 - 0x30c91fff  vecLib armv7  <0c60cd0a60f43d2791d36cb357d30e3c> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x30cce000 - 0x30d0bfff  CoreText armv7  <fb6a72faec2330c4b2cd33c2e9c59588> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x30ec9000 - 0x30faefff  CoreFoundation armv7  <a8444f997111304c9571b3ff974b769c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x30fc9000 - 0x31356fff  UIKit armv7  <c271b78464d93cb7bf28c6e49df293ba> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x31377000 - 0x31464fff  libiconv.2.dylib armv7  <f4146ce07e3031ea8a81fa5516fd77d0> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x31465000 - 0x31466fff  libremovefile.dylib armv7  <e8858a499d663e6a9e3c188521273cc1> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x31477000 - 0x31480fff  CoreVideo armv7  <ea847e6dba2d36b1826b255c73b39539> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x314d1000 - 0x314d3fff  libAccessibility.dylib armv7  <d55f1553d14831a2a5435ae27ef75ef4> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x314d4000 - 0x31525fff  libsqlite3.dylib armv7  <8a41cc6a6d9332308bc415d27577fd24> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x3153f000 - 0x31546fff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  <0a082e1d475432959ba93aa3dbf7fb31> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x3158b000 - 0x31590fff  liblaunch.dylib armv7  <f5ccc8234aea3ebd9a88bd37f0fa23ae> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x315cb000 - 0x315d6fff  libz.1.dylib armv7  <ac706bee36593dc683fd5a96a389d72e> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x31747000 - 0x31747fff  libdnsinfo.dylib armv7  <21415179ffa03f949fa8cc851c6c31c7> /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
0x31748000 - 0x31749fff  libsystem_blocks.dylib armv7  <ccc041df3de73eafb7a59e74cdb1702b> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x3174a000 - 0x3176afff  PrintKit armv7  <e5a01ca9083a36afacc08611a398e2ad> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x31777000 - 0x317b9fff  CoreAudio armv7  <c972fd5f8e89333ca680b9a33587f896> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x31d8c000 - 0x31dc4fff  IOKit armv7  <80ae313ad69d3363935c88e51a11862d> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x31e05000 - 0x31e41fff  libGLImage.dylib armv7  <9d97699e44ee3651ba4ac37e5adec35b> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x33a07000 - 0x33a0cfff  MobileKeyBag armv7  <8c35c090bc373cb181fc26b961b8dba5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x33a0d000 - 0x33a16fff  MobileWiFi armv7  <03d98d5cf6383695aa7d8a88da52f410> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x33b24000 - 0x33b6afff  CoreTelephony armv7  <af7d1e770e5a3ffd8834a57fb5d40557> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x33b6b000 - 0x33b77fff  SpringBoardServices armv7  <c68262667ac8397a949ce4e92dfec7db> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x33c4c000 - 0x33c4efff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <683f321680763e519d61541170ba2133> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x33c4f000 - 0x33c54fff  libcopyfile.dylib armv7  <e57c2b9054b831d9a37119baaa4947cb> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x33d40000 - 0x33d44fff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <a0772a32cd8b3b9194bb0c29807c1c5b> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x33e7a000 - 0x33e7efff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7  <e1cbfe599c96369ca4bdb0dd99d3cd9f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x33e80000 - 0x33f31fff  WebKit armv7  <eb9a0d69c64b3127b2bffd71641add3b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x33f32000 - 0x33f3ffff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7  <0a1e2bb78d5138419ecad8ba0fe42fdd> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x34018000 - 0x3401efff  liblockdown.dylib armv7  <14c89b7346433c1f8675f454531f6ca3> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x342f9000 - 0x342fafff  libdyld.dylib armv7  <41a7b5e5d9983449ab33affed0f635ad> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x34367000 - 0x3436afff  libmacho.dylib armv7  <43311c113a9d3182b7d007129819f029> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x3436b000 - 0x34380fff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7  <e92cfbb83f7b330db19181e797bb3f7b> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x34587000 - 0x3458afff  IOSurface armv7  <ad50e71624583d06b891344d832f9b08> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x3468b000 - 0x346eafff  libBLAS.dylib armv7  <0b36b2272aa33a8c9aa22d99c89d7189> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x3479a000 - 0x348b9fff  Foundation armv7  <09ff368178c5321c9715b9c8d491d53f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x34986000 - 0x34a35fff  QuartzCore armv7  <ef9632c9781f3101916b65e9faae1579> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x34a7e000 - 0x34b42fff  libobjc.A.dylib armv7  <6b51e76fde9f381bb7b3bc5badbfee3a> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x34d28000 - 0x34d5bfff  AppSupport armv7  <0217468bd9f839229a47910b7816b3d5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x34d5c000 - 0x34d63fff  AggregateDictionary armv7  <ab9777b39e8e3026ad64dc90323cad7e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x34d66000 - 0x34e87fff  CoreGraphics armv7  <65f6c8701b563542820a26b0dfc4f6a4> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x34ec8000 - 0x351b5fff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <b855d60dac01310495453bddfd004f0d> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x351e1000 - 0x35216fff  AddressBook armv7  <3f2071a77bc134cd82065eef90d4082f> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x35217000 - 0x352d6fff  CFNetwork armv7  <b09e0d53de9f3bc8bde494780f3cdd4f> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x352d7000 - 0x352f0fff  libRIP.A.dylib armv7  <4825c3e392983aba947eca06555e4480> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x35411000 - 0x35565fff  AudioToolbox armv7  <6619c8c13f8d328e923e797fa8d0df23> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x35606000 - 0x35607fff  CoreSurface armv7  <7b83cd757da73e6e826693c29296d3fa> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x3560c000 - 0x356b5fff  libxml2.2.dylib armv7  <5538d3f2c7d83b88b06168488fe6326b> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x356e0000 - 0x356e5fff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib armv7  <c7cfe523e2d73521abc01587313ef730> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x357d3000 - 0x357f0fff  libsystem_info.dylib armv7  <48016be86e3f3cd9aeee1c6590e1ac6f> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x3583d000 - 0x35841fff  libcache.dylib armv7  <d2f7fd2a352b3cd59c564be34b53cf80> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x35842000 - 0x3584ffff  libdispatch.dylib armv7  <9a0511ad5ebc3db898f1f49ed1a73d34> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x35880000 - 0x358bffff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7  <33dcf9a403ae3fd5971d6030ada2fcab> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x358c0000 - 0x358c0fff  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7  <42d8aa2a31843a6e8bfff745644a7ba5> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x3595f000 - 0x359cefff  ProofReader armv7  <6d843c6aecdd37ae84baa40af8ad7e65> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x359cf000 - 0x35a24fff  libvDSP.dylib armv7  <0221caba81a235c5a896a835e2aac047> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x35b61000 - 0x35b64fff  CaptiveNetwork armv7  <fc834fd33a18341ea7506587ad895703> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x35b65000 - 0x35b7cfff  libsystem_kernel.dylib armv7  <a06ec84e53bf32098b63c0caebdb45b6> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x35bcb000 - 0x35c15fff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7  <b2cac408951c3f3c9ba3cf563e54ce81> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x35c16000 - 0x35c18fff  MobileInstallation armv7  <94b6d6c5d9883175af26764567528127> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x35c1a000 - 0x35c9bfff  libsystem_c.dylib armv7  <a7077267b6743ed3bbdd86d4380c75d9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x35c9c000 - 0x35cd4fff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7  <ccea634795153164a681f0f311f4461d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x36100000 - 0x36204fff  JavaScriptCore armv7  <61a94142e2d23dafa2964190dd46e9e3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x36262000 - 0x36281fff  Bom armv7  <b178e3efb4d733c694bd5a55e57a314f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x36534000 - 0x36b3ffff  WebCore armv7  <07941e59d0a33f94802c16c76238fddf> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x36c14000 - 0x36c43fff  SystemConfiguration armv7  <1d73b8a159363f96bb9c039655c5eae6> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x36c4d000 - 0x36c5bfff  OpenGLES armv7  <5a76beaeaa013f0cbf16e5cb154598ab> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x36c6e000 - 0x36c73fff  libnotify.dylib armv7  <9d7198e91de9386a9e5ea43608a66a57> /usr/lib/system/libnotify.dylib
0x36d76000 - 0x36d76fff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib armv7  <f47c01d627853b328e088b3fdd08e87d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
```

Show test code

```
-(void)showTest
{
    NSLog(@"Show Test");
    lbl.text=@"";
    logOut.hidden=YES;
  //  [self showWithLabelMixed];
 FormViewController *formViewController =[[FormViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"FormViewController" bundle:nil];
    formViewController.userId=fbUserId;
    [formViewController.userId retain];


    formViewController.sex=[fbResult objectForKey:@"sex"];
    [formViewController.sex retain];

    formViewController.country=[[fbResult objectForKey:@"current_location"]objectForKey:@"country"];
    [formViewController.country retain];

    formViewController.city=[[fbResult objectForKey:@"current_location"]objectForKey:@"city"];
    [formViewController.city retain];

    formViewController.birthDate=[fbResult objectForKey:@"birthday_date"];
    [formViewController.birthDate retain];

    formViewController.userImage=imageFb;
    [formViewController.userImage retain];

    [self presentModalViewController:formViewController animated:YES];

   // [self.tabBarController pushViewController:formViewController animated:YES];


}
```

the line 447 in firstViewControlelr is

```
formViewController.country=[[fbResult objectForKey:@"current_location"]objectForKey:@"country"];
```

But there is no line 447 on FormViewController

Comment: can you post the code for `-[FirstViewController showTest]`?

Comment: Great. Now, which line of that code snippet corresponds to line 447 in the file FormViewController.m?

Comment: @gschandler the last line in FormViewController.m it's 353, there are no 447

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the line causing the error is:

```
formViewController.country=[[fbResult objectForKey:@"current_location"]objectForKey:@"country"];
```

(1) Check that formViewController has valid property syntax for `country` -- either synthesized or explicit.

(2) Check that `[fbResult objectForKey:@"current_location"]` is returning a valid dictionary object.

Comment: i use country on formViewController on simulator , it work fine , and current_location return valid dictionary :(

Comment: okay, at the expense of the obvious: have you stepped through this method running the app on the phone using the debugger?

Comment: Can I use the debugger when I run the application on the real device ?I believe that I can't do that ,I did not have an account developer, i don't sign app on xcode code ... i founded this solution on youtube to run app without developer acount , but it work fine , i use it all time , i don't think it's the problem

Comment: Hmm don't know about that -- I'd recommend having a regular developer account if you are going to put apps on the device.  Have you *tried* running the debugger on the device?

Comment: i will take developer account in fiew week. How to run the debugger in device ? just make a breakpoint and run in in the device ?

Comment: yes -- use the debugger as you would in the simulator, just make sure that you've selected 'Device' rather than 'Simulator' as part of the run settings.

Comment: Ok thank you ! your first answer was the answer :) i use another facebook account on the device with no countrie and citie so it return NULL

Answer (score 1):

In your showTest method at line 447:

```
[FirstViewController showTest] (FirstViewController.m:447)
```

You are calling a method on an object that doesn't accept it:

```
-[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 96
```

Could you please edit your question to show us code from the showTest method?

**Edit: Updating question to reflect new information**

Remove the following lines of code:

```
[formViewController.userId retain];
[formViewController.sex retain];
[formViewController.country retain];
[formViewController.city retain];
[formViewController.birthDate retain];
[formViewController.userImage retain];
```

I'm not sure if this is what is causing your bug because you haven't indicated which is the line number that is causing it in this sample. But, what you are doing here is calling retain on values that have already been set by a property setter, and in the case of an object is usually set already.

Comment: Updated. Can you tell us based on your code sample which is line 447?

Comment: i deleted retain... alwayse same problem :( , there are no line 447

Comment: How did you get the crash report that the problem was there " [FirstViewController showTest] (FirstViewController.m:447)
 " , so I found myself next time?